# Arquillian Persistence equivalent for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jboss-arquillian

I'm migrating a Java EE application to Spring Boot.

The integration tests are using Arquillian Persistence to seed the database an finally to check the results:

```
@Test
@UsingDataSet({"datasets/user.yml", "datasets/person-address.yml"})
@ShouldMatchDataSet("expectations/address/person-addresses-after-insert.yml")
public void postMethodShouldCreateAddress() throws Exception {
```

I like to move away from Arquillian. Is there any equivalent for Spring Boot?

Comment: There's the `@Sql` annotation that you can use to execute some `INSERT` statements that could be your dataset. However, there isn't any equivalent for matching datasets, you'll have to do that manually (eg. fetching the data within your test and using an assertion library to make sure that the data matches your expectations). However, you can perfectly use Arquillian with Spring boot, so you could migrate to Spring boot and keep your tests.

Comment: @g00glen00b Thank you. Do you know about any examples how to integrate Arquillian with Spring Boot?